# Rotary potentiometer angle to voltage relation

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer, rotary

I have a 10k rotary potentiometer which turns from 0° to 270°. I wire it to an Arduino with the middle pin (2) connected to an analog input (A0) and the other two pins (1 and 3) connected to 5V and GND.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feAAy5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know the potentiometer is a voltage divider between pin 1, 2 and 3 as above so as expected I get 5 volts on pin 2 when the potentiometer is turned left (0°), 0 volts when the potentiometer is turned right (270°) and something in between in the middle. The problem comes when I try to calculate the angle - voltage function. I expected that it would be a linear function that can be calculated from the two given points (0°, 5V) and (270°, 0V) but when I turn the potentiometer to 135° which is supposed to be the middle point I don't get 2.5 volts instead I get something around 1.5 volts. I also noticed that when close to 270° a single ° in rotation corresponds to a bigger voltage change than when closer to 0°. So is this normal or is my potentiometer busted? And if it is normal why is it so?

### EDIT

I did some measurements and came up with the table below as Umar suggested

```
Degrees   |  Ohms  |   Delta
   0°     |    3   |     -
   45°    |   480  |    480
   90°    |   972  |    492
  135°    |  1704  |    732
  180°    |  3423  |   1719
  225°    |  7280  |   3857
  270°    | 10300  |   3020
```

So Kevin White is correct it seems that I have a tapered audio potentiometer and the function is logarithmic (the blue curve in Kevin's answer). Thanks, everybody for your time and effort.

Comment: Any current draw at pin 2 will cause a voltage drop through your pot.
A voltage follower at pin 2 may reduce or eliminate this effect.

Comment: @Optionparty So what would be the correct way to relate the angle of the pot with the voltage on pin 2?

Comment: Add the datasheet link of the potentiometer.

Comment: It might be a log taper pot

Comment: @Umar, unfortunately, I don't  know model or maker so I can not find the datasheet the only thing on it says A10K

Comment: Can you create a table...measured Resistance Vs angle?.. how many potentiometer do you have.. what if this is a faulty one? Did you try already

Comment: @ScottSeidman I had thought of that possibility so I opened it but the width of the ferrite seemed to be consistent all the way around. I don't know if this is the way to determine if the pot is tapered or not so you might be right after all. It just seems strange because it was a very cheap pot around 10 cents and I think tapered pots are more expensive.

Comment: @Umar It is the only pot I have unfortunately and right now I don't have access to a multimeter but I will make the table as soon as possible. Great idea!!

Comment: Please make sure you isolate the remaining circuits from the potentiometer.

Comment: @Umar yes I will disconnect it completely and measure carefully without touching the terminals

Comment: What is your ultimate goal ? To measure angle or voltage.

Comment: @Optionparty I was actually trying to use the potentiometer as a kind of rotary encoder for dc motor speed control and I noticed that I did not get the middle value for the middle position and I  was curious about why is it happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is almost certainly an audio taper version. They have a pseudo-logarithmic law that works better for audio applications because of the way that we perceive loudness.

The A10K means audio taper potentiometer 10 kilo-ohms. One marked B10K would have a linear law that does what you expect.

[image: Pot laws]

The picture was taken from this site [Resistor Guide](http://www.resistorguide.com/potentiometer-taper/)